# Error: No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [socket timeout calling ismaster on ...]

Tags: r, mongodb, shiny, shinyapps, mongolite

I am wondering why shinyapps.io no longer can connect to a mongoDB from Atlas. I have done countless projects using mongoAtlas and shinyapps.io.

As of today, any new app I publish does not allow me to connect to my mongoDB.

In my logs I get an error:
No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [socket timeout calling ismaster on 'cluster0-shard-00-00-02dsl.mongodb.net:27017']

The code runs perfectly on Rstudio Cloud, my local pc and my friends local pc. But shinyapps.io is having a hard time.

UI.R

```
library(mongolite)
shinyUI(fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            tableOutput("table")
        )
    )
))
```

Server.R

```
library(shiny)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    url = "mongodb://jwrong:<mypass>@cluster0-shard-00-00-02dsl.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-02dsl.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-02dsl.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=false"
    df.orats = mongo(collection = "df.orats", db = "test", url = url, verbose = T)



    d = df.orats$find()

    output$table <- renderTable({
        d
    })

})
```

Comment: Did you check the IP whitelist (might be your server IP has been changed)?

Comment: Hi @Neodan, I did check my whitelist. I currently have it set to 0.0.0.0/0 to make sure shinyserver can access it. Could you explain a bit more (if you think I should have it set to something different). Thanks

Comment: I am facing this issue multiple times, have checked all ports and allowed all IP addresses. but the issue still persists as Error : No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [socket timeout calling ismaster ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try now. Probably, there was some issue with MongoDB or shinyapps.io. Rather the second one. Now everything works.

Comment: Yes! They are up and running. It was a shiny issue I tried connecting with MySQL as well last night

Comment: I am facing this issue multiple times, have checked all ports and allowed all IP addresses. but the issue still persists as Error : No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [socket timeout calling ismaster ...